# Matching records by ID and displaying non-matching columns in TSQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

In SQL Server I have two tables, Registrar Records and Teacher Records which are identical. The first part of the query matches on the student ID and shows whether or not a match was found in a dynamic column (that part I did already).

An additional dynamic column should list out all the columns that didn't match - I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without making a gigantic Case expression since that would have many possibilities, this is what I have so far:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF

SELECT TR.*,
        CASE WHEN RR.StudentID IS NULL THEN 'NO MATCH'
             WHEN RR.StudentID IS NOT NULL AND RR.FirstName = TR.FirstName
                                           AND RR.LastName = TR.LastName
                                           AND RR.Floor = TR.Floor
                                           AND RR.FirstQuarterGrade = TR.FirstQuarterGrade
                                           AND RR.SecondQuarterGrade = TR.SecondQuarterGrade
                                           AND RR.ThirdQuarterGrade = TR.ThirdQuarterGrade
                                           AND RR.FinalGrade = TR.FinalGrade THEN 'MATCH'
            ELSE 'MATCH WITH ISSUE' END AS MatchResult
        --TO DO: Add a ISSUE column; lists columns with mismatch
FROM TeacherRecords TR
      LEFT JOIN RegistrarRecords RR ON RR.StudentID = TR.StudentID
```

If a script is needed for the table here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RegistrarRecords](
    [StudentID] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Floor] [int] NULL,
    [Room] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [FirstQuarterGrade] [int] NULL,
    [SecondQuarterGrade] [int] NULL,
    [ThirdQuarterGrade] [int] NULL,
    [FinalGrade] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split this query into two parts

- First find all the issues
- Then check if there are any issues in doing the final select

Here is sample code to do so. The Issue_List field contains a comma-separated list of all the columns with issues (e.g., 'Floor, FirstQuarterGrade'). If this field is empty, then it represents that there are no issues.

```
WITH TR_Match_Info AS
    (SELECT TR.*, 
        RR.StudentID AS RR_StudentID,
        '' + CASE WHEN RR.FirstName = TR.FirstName THEN '' ELSE 'FirstName, ' END
           + CASE WHEN RR.LastName = TR.LastName THEN '' ELSE 'LastName, ' END
           + CASE WHEN RR.Floor = TR.Floor THEN '' ELSE 'Floor, ' END
           + CASE WHEN RR.FirstQuarterGrade = TR.FirstQuarterGrade THEN '' ELSE 'FirstQuarterGrade, ' END
           + CASE WHEN RR.SecondQuarterGrade = TR.SecondQuarterGrade THEN '' ELSE 'SecondQuarterGrade, ' END
           + CASE WHEN RR.ThirdQuarterGrade = TR.ThirdQuarterGrade THEN '' ELSE 'ThirdQuarterGrade, ' END
           + CASE WHEN RR.FinalGrade = TR.FinalGrade THEN '' ELSE 'FinalGrade, ' END
           AS Issue_List
    FROM TeacherRecords TR
          LEFT JOIN RegistrarRecords RR ON RR.StudentID = TR.StudentID
    )
SELECT  [StudentID],
        [FirstName],
        [LastName],
        [Floor],
        [Room],
        [FirstQuarterGrade],
        [SecondQuarterGrade],
        [ThirdQuarterGrade],
        [FinalGrade],
        CASE WHEN RR_StudentID IS NULL THEN 'NO MATCH'
             WHEN Issue_List = '' THEN 'MATCH'
             ELSE 'MATCH WITH ISSUE' END 
             AS MatchResult,
        CASE WHEN RR_StudentID IS NULL THEN ''
             WHEN LEN(Issue_List) > 0 THEN LEFT(Issue_List, LEN(Issue_List) - 1)
             ELSE Issue_List
             END AS Match_Issues
FROM TR_Match_Info;
```

Note that the issue checks above are based on your code. You should review how NULLs are  handled - if the values are both NULL it flags it as an issue (e.g., when checking whether NULL = NULL the result is NULL so it goes to the ELSE component of these CASE expressions).

Comment: I really appreciate this smart nested query! I'm going to try it out and mark this as an answer if it works out! Also thanks for being considerate about the NULLs, in my actual query I'm handling that with ISNULL and RTRIM functions. I didn't include it in the question to keep things brief and just address the core problem.

Comment: I faced an issue with LEN(Issue_List) - 1, because LEN will not count trailing space, so I corrected the issue with WHEN LEN(Issue_List) > 0 THEN LEFT (Issue_List, LEN(Issue_List) - 1) ELSE IssueList. If you agree with this and update, or update with alternate solution that works I can mark this as a definitive answer! Thanks!

Comment: Ah good point! When there are no issues, LEN(IssueList) would be 0, therefore the LEFT with LEN() - 1 fails. I was going to put in a slightly different version (e.g., `WHEN Issue_List = '' THEN Issue_List` but that means also meant handling NULLs etc - the method you put in works and is safer - the answer has been updated as such.